# How to delete AWS child account when removed from the organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

Is there an intuitive way of automatically deleting child accounts upon their removal from an AWS organization? this would be particularly useful when treating accounts like environments.

If there's a better way to handle this (possibly i am just thinking about this the wrong way?) I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: Can you just close the account which will result in removing? I have never tried so not sure if accounts in an org can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly not. AWS Account can be [closed only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_close.html) using console:

> You can close an account **only by using the Billing and Cost Management console**, not by using the AWS Organizations console or its tools.

This includes accounts in AWS Org as well.